# How to use hash_key in Redis Objects gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, redis

I need to store a hash into Redis using [redis-objects](https://github.com/nateware/redis-objects) gem. From the README, they have `hash_key`. But there are no examples for that.

I get an error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `fantasy_points_details=' for #<InningPlayer:0x007f820adb68a0>
```

when I do:

```
 inning_player_instance.fantasy_points_details = {a: 1}
```

for a model like this:

```
class InningPlayer < ActiveRecord::Base
    include Redis::Objects
    hash_key :fantasy_points_details
end
```

But the getter works:

```
 > inning_player_instance.fantasy_points_details
 => #<Redis::HashKey:0x007f820adf4470>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the update method on the [HashKey class](https://github.com/nateware/redis-objects/blob/master/lib/redis/hash_key.rb):

```
>  inning_player_instance.fantasy_points_details.update({"a"=>"3", "c"=>"4"})
=> "OK"
```

To read:

```
> ip.fantasy_points_details.all
=> {"a"=>"3", "c"=>"4"}
```

Comment: Also, you have to do `inning_player_instance.fantasy_points_details["a"] = 1` to set and get a hash value one at a time.